# What to do with single-picture events in iPhoto?

Tags: photos.app

I use iPhoto to manage my pictures.  I have, therefore, over several years gained quite a set of *Events* as iPhoto calls them.

I also have lots of one-off pictures that people send me that I want to keep.  Not sure they deserve their own event, though, as the *Events* page is becoming pretty large.

What is a reasonable way to manage these pictures (and I hope that this questions meets the subjectivity benchmark)?  Make a "Single Picture" event?  Do pictures even have to be part of events, but if not, how do I find them again?

Comment: This is an excellent question. I myself followed glen’s advice and created a “Misc” event where I drop all the single ones… wallpapers, sshots, etc. things that I want to keep but don’t look nice in “untitled” events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photos need to be part of events; deleting a photo from an event deletes the photo from your Photo Library (unlike albums where deleting the photo just removes it from the album). If I was you I'd create a 'One-Off' or 'Photos I like' event.

You could create a big event for everything you don't want to be in its own event folder. This should let the Events feature be used for what it's designed for - organising your photos by significant dates. If Events seems like too much hassle then you can just ignore them all together, make your own albums and organise them manually.

Personally I just use events to find photos from 'the picnic' or 'that time we went to the airport', I don't bother organising or sorting my events.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, what I do, is make a folder called "Random Pics", and whenever I have single picture events, I just grab them in the Events view and drag them on top of the the "Random Pics" event and it adds the pics to that event and gets rid of the single photo event.